# ASP MVC: Ajax change textbox value which is implemented in a different view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view named `Index`, and 2 partial views `_Grid` and `_Project`. 
The partialview _Project is a pop-up which is visible once the user clicks on the button to add data, think of it like adding a user.
Now, I am trying to change a textbox value which is inside the partial view `_Grid` once the user click on the button inside the `_Project` pop-up.

Inside the _Grid partialview:

```
<input id="CurrentOrder" type="hidden" value=""/>
```

In javascript once the button inside the pop-up(partialview _Project) is pressed:

```
function AddTimeReg() {
//code 
if (date && shopdoc && ((convertedStartTime && convertedEndTime) || hours)) {
        $.ajax({
// more code 
// change the value of textbox
 $("#Grid #CurrentOrder").val(salesorder);
```

The input type is inside the Grid partialview in a div named Grid.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?
I want the textbox have the value of salesorder.

Edit: For the one who wants the entire code:
Javascript File:

```
function AddTimeReg() {

    var salesorder = $("#SalesOrder").val();
    var shopdoc = $("#Shopdoc").val().trim();
    var starttime = $("#StartTime").val().trim()
    var convertedStartTime = starttime.replace(/\./g, ':')
    var endtime = $("#EndTime").val().trim()
    var convertedEndTime = endtime.split('.').join(':');

    var hours = Math.round(Number($("#Hours").val().trim().replace(DecimalSeparator(), '.')) * 100 / 100);
    var date = $("#Date").val().trim();
    var info = $("#Info").val().trim();
    var timeRegLineNr = 0;
    var isEditing = $("#Project #Date").prop('disabled');
    if (isEditing) {
        timeRegLineNr = $($(".highlight")[0]).children(".td-TimeRegLineNr").text();
    }

    if (date && shopdoc && ((convertedStartTime && convertedEndTime) || hours)) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: appPath + '/TimeReg/ShopDoc',
            data: {
                regDate: date, salesOrder: salesorder, shopDoc: shopdoc, startTime: convertedStartTime, endTime: convertedEndTime,
                hours: hours, info: info, timeRegLineNr: timeRegLineNr
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    var mySessionVariable = shopdoc
                    ClosePopup();
                    ShowGrid();
                    $("#Grid #CurrentOrder").val(salesorder);
                    var timerId = setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#dialog #TimerId").val("");
                        $("#dialog").modal("hide");
                    }, timeToClose);

                    $("#dialog #TimerId").val(timerId);
                }
                $("#dialog .modal-body").html(response.message);
                $("#dialog #dialog-title").html(response.title);
                $("#dialog").modal("show");


            },
            error: function (response) {
                $("#dialog .modal-body").html(msgErrorDuringRequest);
                $("#dialog #dialog-title").html(errorTitle);
                $("#dialog").modal("show");

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Inside Index:

```
<div id="Main" style="@mainDisplay">
    <div style="margin:10px;">
        <input id="regDate" type="@regDateType" value="@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()" />
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="@Resources.Ok" onclick="ShowGrid()">
    </div>
    <div id="Grid">
        @if ((bool)ViewBag.ShowGrid)
        {
            Html.RenderAction("Grid", new { login = (string)ViewBag.Login, regDate = DateTime.Now });
        }
```

Inside the _Grid partialview there is the textbox:

```
<input id="CurrentOrder" type="hidden" value=""/>
```

And inside the Project partial view there is a button which calls the javascript Action

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code, please?

Comment: As I understand your question correct, than After submitting the modal(_Project partial view) you need to make a ajax call to bind your grid again.

Comment: $("#CurrentOrder").val(salesorder); should do it. Unless 1. you have multiple items called CurrentOrder.  2. CurrentOrder does not actually exist on the page. 3. Your modal is in a IFrame

Comment: You input type `CurrentOrder` is a hidden field not textbox right?

Comment: @KevDevMan The javascript function is called on the partialview _Project while the hidden field is implemented in the _Grid partialview

Answer (score 0):

You have two partial.Call first partial then if call other partial, you might use ajax call.